# C# XNA Out of Memory Exception when using trying to Draw

Tags: c#, xna, out-of-memory, draw, spritebatch

From what I have seen in other questions it seems like I am instantiating new stuff in my draw code that will take up a lot of memory, but looking through other code Im using as a reference, Im not sure where the problem is.

```
namespace Crucible
{
    public class Crucible : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        //Drawing vars
        public int renderLeft;
        public int renderRight;
        public int renderUp;
        public int renderDown;
        public Tile currentTile;
        public Rectangle target;
        public Rectangle source;
        public Color tint;
        public Texture2D img;
        //
        public static int baseTileWidth = 16;
        public static int baseTileHeight = 16;
        public static int mapWidthTile = 8400;
        public static int mapHeightTile = 2400;
        public static int mapWidthPixel = 8400 * baseTileWidth;
        public static int mapHeightPixel = 2400 * baseTileHeight;
        public static int screenWidth;
        public static int screenHeight;
        public static Player mainPlayer;
        Tile[,] worldTilesFor; //Foreground Tiles
        Tile[,] worldTilesBack; //Foreground Tiles

        Texture2D coalOreSprite;
        Texture2D dirtSprite;

        public Crucible()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            mainPlayer = new Player("tim", 1);
            worldTilesFor = new Tile[8400,2400];
            worldTilesBack = new Tile[8400, 2400];
            for (int i = 0; i < worldTilesFor.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < worldTilesFor.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    worldTilesFor[i, j] = new Tile(0,i,j);
                    if (j >= 1200)
                    {
                        worldTilesFor[i, j].tileID = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < worldTilesBack.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < worldTilesBack.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    worldTilesBack[i, j] = new Tile(0, i, j);
                    if (j < 1200)
                    {
                        worldTilesFor[i, j].tileID = 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            screenWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
            screenHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;
            base.IsMouseVisible = true;
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            coalOreSprite = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tile_coal ore");
            dirtSprite = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Tile_Dirt");
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            renderLeft = (int)Math.Floor(mainPlayer.position.X) - (screenWidth / 2);
            if (renderLeft < 0)
            {
                renderLeft = 0;
            }

            renderRight = (int)Math.Ceiling(mainPlayer.position.X) + (screenWidth / 2);
            if (renderRight > mapWidthPixel)
            {
                renderRight = mapWidthPixel;
            }

            renderUp = (int)Math.Floor(mainPlayer.position.Y) - (screenHeight / 2);
            if (renderUp < 0)
            {
                renderUp = 0;
            }

            renderDown = (int)Math.Floor(mainPlayer.position.Y) + (screenHeight / 2);
            if (renderDown > mapHeightPixel)
            {
                renderDown = mapHeightPixel;
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            for (int i = renderLeft; i < renderRight; i++)
            {
                for (int j = renderUp; j < renderDown; j++)
                {
                    currentTile = worldTilesBack[i / 16, j / 16];
                    DrawTile(currentTile);
                }
            }
            for (int i = renderLeft; i < renderRight; i++)
            {
                for (int j = renderUp; j < renderDown; j++)
                {
                    currentTile = worldTilesFor[i/16, j/16];
                    DrawTile(currentTile);
                }
            }


            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public void DrawTile(Tile tileIn)
        {
            switch (tileIn.tileID)
            {
                case 1:
                    img = dirtSprite;
                    break;
                default:
                    img = dirtSprite;
                    break;
            }

            if (tileIn.foreground)
            {
                tint = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                tint = Color.Gray; //tint background objects grey
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(dirtSprite, new Rectangle((int)(tileIn.posX * baseTileWidth - mainPlayer.position.X + screenWidth / 2), (int)(tileIn.posY * baseTileHeight - mainPlayer.position.Y + screenHeight / 2), baseTileWidth, baseTileHeight), new Rectangle?(new Rectangle(tileIn.frameX * 16, tileIn.frameY * 16, 16, 16)), tint); //error is thrown here at the source rectangle
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance on what is causing the error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `worldTilesFor` and `worldTilesBack` arrays. You don't show what the `Tile` class looks like, but even if we assume that each `Tile` holds 100 bytes of data, which is think is a low guess, that's 8400 * 2400 = 20,160,000 Tile instances * 100 bytes, for about 2 Gigabytes of ram PER ARRAY, 4 for both of them.

I assume this is how you store your map.  You will either need a smaller map, or you will need some way to virtualize your map by storing it on disk, and loading it in chunks as needed.

Comment: I was thinking it would be a problem, each tile classs is around 5 bytes right now. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Keep in mind that even a completely empty object reference takes 8 bytes on x64 operating systems, and 4 on x86.  With arrays declared that size, even before instantiating `Tile` instances, you are using a significant amount of memory.

Comment: This is interesting to me as looking a the code from a game I decompiled, it creates and handles the same array (and a ton more) with little to no problem